# I need some SQL help trying to find what is not in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help. I tried this and it does not work.
I selected all the data I needed and tried to say what's not in 
the original file.

Could someone show me the correct way?

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM acknowledgement t1
    where t1.st01 = '110' 
    and (t1.shipment ='S640D14268424' or t1.Shipment ='S640D14268924' or
      t1.Shipment ='S640D14268925' or t1.Shipment ='S646D14261190' or
      t1.Shipment ='S646I14265886' or t1.Shipment ='S640D14268423' ...)
   AND [shipment] 
   NOT IN(
   SELECT [shipment] FROM acknowledgement 
   )
```

Any help would be useful.

Comment: what r u trying to achieve..ur last condition is to select all rows whose shipment is not in acknowledgement...and u r taking data from same table..so it will be always no record

Comment: I have records selected that some are not in the table.  I want to try to find the same records that do not exist in that table, without doing 1 at a time.

Comment: You can say `t1.Shipment in ('S640D14272953', 'S640D14276996' ... )` and it does the same, less characters and looks better.

Comment: are you trying to find duplicate records?

Comment: how can you find shipment in acknowledgement table which is not in find acknowledgement table?

Comment: its One table, acknowledgement table.  I am trying to find the shipments that do not exist in my list.

Comment: This SQL does not give me the right answer is not a question. You are excluding every row in the not in!   I want every row from the table where the row is not in the table.   A big -1

Comment: You should improve your question. What are you doing and what you hope to get?

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT  'S640D14268424' AS Shipment
 UNION SELECT  'S640D14268924'
 UNION SELECT  'S640D14268925' 
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14261190'
 UNION SELECT  'S646I14265886'  
 UNION SELECT  'S640D14268423'  
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14269951'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14269939'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14269034'  
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14269962'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14269953'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14271620'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14269030'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14269941'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14269251'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14273089'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14272388'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14273197'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D14273399'
 UNION SELECT  'S640D14273543'
 UNION SELECT  'S640D14272952'
 UNION SELECT  'S640D14272953'
 UNION SELECT  'S640D14276996'
 UNION SELECT  'S640D14277005'
 UNION SELECT  'S640D14277006'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D148047394'
 UNION SELECT  'S640D14277004'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049311'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049791'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049797'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049806'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049781'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049557'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049064'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049561'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049794'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049362'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049361'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049792'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049808'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049788'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049365'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049800'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049790'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049799'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049803'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049784'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049522'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049340'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049796'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049687'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049491'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049499'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049484'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049486'
 UNION SELECT  'S646D158049494') numbers_to_look
 WHERE Shipment NOT IN 
 (SELECT [shipment] FROM acknowledgement WHERE shipment>'' )
```

Better way to do this is create a temp table to store the numbers you want to check.

Comment: That example looks good, I copied it and tried it to no avail.  I know the first 5 records are not there and some of the others are there.  That should show me the first 5 records at least.  But when I ran this sample it found 0 .

Comment: do you have null shipment values in your acknowledgement table? If so, add the WHERE Shipment>'' (or IS NOT NULL) in the second sub query.